# Print multiple uploaded document from a web application

Tags: php, pdf, printing

I want to know if this is possible to print all attached pdf from an object.
(i'm afraid not, but better asking ;D)

*context:*

*User uploads multiple pdf file in his account, then later, he clicks on "print all the pdf attachements", instead of downloading and then one by one clicking on "print"*

Thanks.

Comment: this is a good question, i know you can initiate the print window by using Javascript.. `window.print()`.. IBM does this with some of their CRM/ERP software.. they concatenate attachments and open the print dialog.

Comment: i refer you to list all attached files in user directory and then print all of them continuously  with a loop.

Comment: Your best bet here is to use your PHP-PDF manipulation tool of choice to merge the PDFs into a single document. The user then only has to print it once - but you can't automatically send it to the printer and bypass the Print dialog - even if you could, it would be a client side job (Javascript) not server side (PHP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you can go about this with either just JS or a combination of PHP and js (and perhaps server-side programs that can be called by PHP):

1. Have the target document be a php file which programatically join all the PDFs into a single document (for instance, with pdftk) and then outputs the joined file with PDF headers. This file would be loaded into an iframe which you could call `window.print()` on with JavaScript.
2. Use javascript's `window.print()` function to target several hidden iframes each of which has one of the PDFs loaded in it. The major drawback of this approach is that it will generate multiple print dialogue boxes.

Both of these approaches rely on the user having the necessary settings and plugins to actually load PDFs within the browser window, but if they don't they'll be prompted to download the large file/multiple files.

Comment: The 1) sounds good, i just hope pdftk joins the PDF correctly. The 2) has one major drawbacks, what if users has 20 files attached ? 20 iframe and 20 print dialog box :o

Comment: Yeah, #1 is an easier approach for the user, it's just a little more work for you. I've used pdftk a lot, and joining files is super easy and reliable. Calling it from PHP is sometimes annoying, but let me know if you have trouble, as I've set this up in a few environments.

Answer (score 1):

This can not be done with PHP. Why? Well, PHP is a server-side script. It has no possibilities to access the user's printer.

To my knowledge there is no solution with javascript either. Mike made a good point with the printer dialog being accessible through a javascript command but that is where it stops. This is a good thing though, would you want a page you enter to be able to use your printer without your permission?

Answer (score 1):

Best way is probably to concatenate all the pdf into a single document server side then allow the user to download and print that.  This is what manuscriptcentral and probably other online academic peer review systems do.